# How to specify height and width in nuxt/image

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxt3

```
<nuxt-picture
  loading="lazy"
  src="/dummy.jpg"
  format="avif,webp"
  fit="cover"
  alt="test"
/>
```

```
picture{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

Then how to specify its height and width 100% without css?

```
<nuxt-picture
  loading="lazy"
  src="/dummy.jpg"
  format="avif,webp"
  height="100%"
  width="100%"
  fit="cover"
  alt="test"
/>
```

This code doesn't work well.Image is not scaled.